# How can i open an infowindow on markerclusterer click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I'm trying to open an infowindow on markerClusterer click

The plugin file contains:-

```
(function( $ ){
$.extend({
    mapsearch: function(options){
        options = $.extend({
        map:null,
        searchWhere:null,
        searchWhat:null,
        activeInfowindow:null,
    }, options);

    var markersFeed ={"recordsFiltered":5,"data":[{"id":"19","records":"1","geohash":"dpxpqjc","location":{"minlat":43.493499755859,"minlon":-79.891204833984,"maxlat":43.494873046875,"maxlon":-79.889831542969,"medlat":43.49,"medlon":-79.89}},{"id":"18","records":"1","geohash":"dpxrcqy","location":{"minlat":43.586883544922,"minlon":-79.741516113281,"maxlat":43.588256835938,"maxlon":-79.740142822266,"medlat":43.59,"medlon":-79.74}},{"id":"14","records":"2","geohash":"dpzc2cm","location":{"minlat":43.820343017578,"minlon":-79.061737060547,"maxlat":43.821716308594,"maxlon":-79.060363769531,"medlat":43.82,"medlon":-79.06}},{"id":"16","records":"1","geohash":"dpzc3t4","location":{"minlat":43.840942382812,"minlon":-79.032897949219,"maxlat":43.842315673828,"maxlon":-79.031524658203,"medlat":43.84,"medlon":-79.03}}],"zoom":"10"};

plugin = this;



plugin.markerCombine = function(markers) {
    var index = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0;i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log(markers[i].records);
        total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(markers[i].records);
        index++;
    }


    return {
        text: total,
        index: index
    };
}


plugin.addMarker=function(lat,lng,records,geohash, map){
    var marker = options.map.addMarker({
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        records: records,
        label:records,
        geohash: geohash,     
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
        plugin.markerClick(marker,options.map); 
    });

}



plugin.clearMarkers=function(){
    options.map.markerClusterer.clearMarkers();

    var i = 0,
        l = options.map.markers.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        options.map.markers[i].setMap(null)
    }
    options.map.markerClusterer.markers = []
    options.map.markers = []; 

}

plugin.bindMapListeners = function(map){

map.addListener(options.map.markerClusterer,'clusterclick', function(cluster){
    plugin.clusterClick(cluster,options.map);   
}); 

}

plugin.clusterClick = function(cluster,map){

    var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                '<div class="iw-title">Loading</div>' +
                '<div class="iw-content">' +
                '<br/>Searching<br/>'+
                '</div>' +
              '</div>';
    options.activeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var pos = cluster.getCenter();
    options.activeInfowindow.setPosition(pos);
    options.activeInfowindow.setContent(content2);
    options.activeInfowindow.open(map);
}

plugin.mapSearchEvents = function(map){


    google.maps.event.addListener(map.map, 'dragend', function() {

    plugin.search(map);


    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(map.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    plugin.search(map);
    }); 
}




//retrieve markers for existing bounds and apply
plugin.search =function(map, params){
    //remove existing markers
    plugin.clearMarkers();

    var mapBounds = options.map.getBounds();

    var bounds = {}
    bounds.latMax = mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    bounds.latMin = mapBounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    bounds.lonMax = mapBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    bounds.lonMin = mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng();

    zoom = options.map.getZoom();


    $.each( markersFeed.data, function( list, blip ) {
        console.log(blip);
    plugin.addMarker(blip.location.medlat,blip.location.medlon,blip.records,blip.geohash, options.map);

    });
    options.map.markerClusterer.setCalculator(plugin.markerCombine);

    plugin.bindMapListeners(options.map);





}


plugin.markerClick = function(marker){
url="/ajaxSearch/searchGeohash/"

    var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                '<div class="iw-title">Loading</div>' +
                '<div class="iw-content" id="'+marker.geohash+'">' +
                '<br/>Searching<br/>'+
                '</div>' +
                //'<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
              '</div>';
    options.activeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(100,100),

    // Assign a maximum value for the width of the infowindow allows
    // greater control over the various content elements
        maxWidth: 340
    });

    options.activeInfowindow.close();
    options.activeInfowindow.open(options.map,marker);

}





plugin.drawMap =function(lat,lng, target, zoom, params,bounds){
if (options.map !== null) {
options.map.markerClusterer.clearMarkers(); 
}
   map = new GMaps({
    div: target,
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    zoom: zoom,
   scrollwheel: false,
     markerClusterer: function(map) {
        options= {
        zoomOnClick: false, 
        gridSize: 50,
        styles: [{
            height: 39,
            width: 43,
        }],
        }
      return new MarkerClusterer(map, [], options);


    }

    });
    options.map = map;
    //options.map = options.map;
    //console.log(options);
    if(typeof bounds != 'undefined'){
        options.map.fitBounds(bounds);

    }

    //bind info box to popup and get gridsquare bound submit mapsearch



    //full map search
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(options.map.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    plugin.search();

    });

plugin.mapSearchEvents(options.map);

    return options.map;
}



    return this;



    }
});
})( jQuery );
```

The html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Membawhen</title>
<style>
#homeMap{width:100%; height:400px;}
</style>

</head>

<body >

<div id="homeMap"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&sensor=true"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r287/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.21/gmaps.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {


var map =  $.mapsearch();
map.drawMap(43.653226,-79.383184, '#homeMap', 9);    
});


 </script>


 </body> 
 </html>
```

The first marker to be clicked opens fine but no subsequent clicks on  any marker will open.

The cluster infowindows never open

The clicks are calling the functions (I can alert and log etc) but I can't get the infowindow to open, in console the only error showing is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined    from infowindow.js
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289634/googlemap-api-v3-can-i-get-content-from-marker/34291273#34291273) contains a working infowindow on the marker cluster.

Comment: bear with me I have updated the code and will edit with comments

Comment: There are no markers in that code.  It doesn't look like a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you have URLs in the posted code that aren't available to us.

Comment: the markers are retrieved by ajax, the markers are added fine and are visible on the map. 

The first marker to be clicked opens fine but subsequent clicks on any marker does nothing.

Clicks on clusters don't open an infowindow either.

The first click on he first marker is fine.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue and doesn't depend on AJAX (that isn't likely to have anything to do with your problem)

Comment: Edited to add test feed data, and included the html, because I am calling  marker clusterer from google the clusters have no csss.

This recreates the problem

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`, which may explain the issue.  Have you investigated that?

Comment: I have had that error marked in this post iin the beginning thats trying to trace. I can log the cluster or marker from within the click event and it looks fine. I don't know what is undefined.

Comment: The javascript error is due to an incorrect argument being passed to the `InfoWindow.open` method, the first argument is a `Gmaps` object, not a `google.maps.Map` object. I don't see icons for the clusters, are they working in your code?  If so, where do they come from.

Comment: icons for cluster don't show when calling markerclusterer from cdn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your code `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` on this line:

```
options.activeInfowindow.open(options.map, marker);
```

Because `options.map` is a `Gmaps` object, not a `google.maps.Map` object.  If I change that to `options.map.map` (which is a reference to the `google.map.Map` object), that error goes away and the InfoWindows on the markers work.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgpLxf3/2/)

When I look at the 'clusterclick' issue, if I change this:

```
map.addListener(options.map.markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
      plugin.clusterClick(cluster, options.map);
});
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(options.map.markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
      plugin.clusterClick(cluster, options.map);
});
```

I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: content2 is not defined`.  If I fix that (by using `content` instead, which is defined), I get an InfoWindow on the marker cluster.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgpLxf3/5/)

If you want a single infowindow open at a time, you need to create it once and reuse that marker as needed:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgpLxf3/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var map = $.mapsearch();
  map.drawMap(43.653226, -79.383184, '#homeMap', 9);
});
(function($) {
  $.extend({
    mapsearch: function(options) {
      options = $.extend({
        map: null,
        searchWhere: null,
        searchWhat: null,
        activeInfowindow: null,
      }, options);
      plugin = this;
      plugin.markerCombine = function(markers) {
        var index = 0;
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          console.log(markers[i].records);
          total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(markers[i].records);
          index++;
        }
        return {
          text: total,
          index: index
        };
      }
      plugin.addMarker = function(lat, lng, records, geohash, map) {
        var marker = options.map.addMarker({
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng,
          records: records,
          label: records,
          geohash: geohash,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          plugin.markerClick(marker, options.map);
        });
      }
      plugin.clearMarkers = function() {
        options.map.markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
        var i = 0,
          l = options.map.markers.length;
        for (i; i < l; i++) {
          options.map.markers[i].setMap(null)
        }
        options.map.markerClusterer.markers = []
        options.map.markers = [];
      }
      plugin.bindMapListeners = function(map) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(options.map.markerClusterer, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
          plugin.clusterClick(cluster, options.map.map);
        });
      }
      plugin.clusterClick = function(cluster, map) {
        var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
          '<h4>Cluster</h4><div class="iw-title">Loading</div>' +
          '<div class="iw-content">' +
          '<br/>Searching<br/>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        if (!options.activeInfowindow || !options.activeInfowindow.setContent) {
          options.activeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            maxWidth: 340
          });
        }
        // options.activeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var pos = cluster.getCenter();
        options.activeInfowindow.setPosition(pos);
        options.activeInfowindow.setContent(content);
        options.activeInfowindow.open(map);
      }
      plugin.mapSearchEvents = function(map) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(map.map, 'dragend', function() {
            plugin.search(map);
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(map.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            plugin.search(map);
          });
        }
        //retrieve markers for existing bounds and apply
      plugin.search = function(map, params) {
        //remove existing markers
        plugin.clearMarkers();
        var mapBounds = options.map.getBounds();
        var bounds = {}
        bounds.latMax = mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        bounds.latMin = mapBounds.getSouthWest().lat();
        bounds.lonMax = mapBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        bounds.lonMin = mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        zoom = options.map.getZoom();
        $.each(markersFeed.data, function(list, blip) {
          console.log(blip);
          plugin.addMarker(blip.location.medlat, blip.location.medlon, blip.records, blip.geohash, options.map);
        });
        options.map.markerClusterer.setCalculator(plugin.markerCombine);
        plugin.bindMapListeners(options.map);
      }
      plugin.markerClick = function(marker) {
        url = "/ajaxSearch/searchGeohash/"

        var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
          '<h4>Marker</h4><div class="iw-title">Loading</div>' +
          '<div class="iw-content" id="' + marker.geohash + '">' +
          '<br/>Searching<br/>' +
          '</div>' +
          //'<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
          '</div>';
        if (!options.activeInfowindow || !options.activeInfowindow.setContent) {
          options.activeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            maxWidth: 340
          });
        }
        /* options.activeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: content,
          maxWidth: 340
        }); */
        options.activeInfowindow.setContent(content);
        options.activeInfowindow.close();
        options.activeInfowindow.open(options.map.map, marker);
      }
      plugin.drawMap = function(lat, lng, target, zoom, params, bounds) {
        if (options.map !== null) {
          options.map.markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
        }
        map = new GMaps({
          div: target,
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng,
          zoom: zoom,
          scrollwheel: false,
          markerClusterer: function(map) {
            options = {
              zoomOnClick: false,
              gridSize: 50,
              styles: [{
                height: 39,
                width: 43,
                url: 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/images/m1.png',
                anchor: [20, 0],
              }]
            }
            return new MarkerClusterer(map, [], options);
          }
        });
        options.map = map;
        if (typeof bounds != 'undefined') {
          options.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(options.map.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
          plugin.search();
        });
        plugin.mapSearchEvents(options.map);
        return options.map;
      }
      return this;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
var markersFeed = {
  "recordsFiltered": 5,
  "data": [{
    "id": "19",
    "records": "1",
    "geohash": "dpxpqjc",
    "location": {
      "minlat": 43.493499755859,
      "minlon": -79.891204833984,
      "maxlat": 43.494873046875,
      "maxlon": -79.889831542969,
      "medlat": 43.49,
      "medlon": -79.89
    }
  }, {
    "id": "18",
    "records": "1",
    "geohash": "dpxrcqy",
    "location": {
      "minlat": 43.586883544922,
      "minlon": -79.741516113281,
      "maxlat": 43.588256835938,
      "maxlon": -79.740142822266,
      "medlat": 43.59,
      "medlon": -79.74
    }
  }, {
    "id": "14",
    "records": "2",
    "geohash": "dpzc2cm",
    "location": {
      "minlat": 43.820343017578,
      "minlon": -79.061737060547,
      "maxlat": 43.821716308594,
      "maxlon": -79.060363769531,
      "medlat": 43.82,
      "medlon": -79.06
    }
  }, {
    "id": "16",
    "records": "1",
    "geohash": "dpzc3t4",
    "location": {
      "minlat": 43.840942382812,
      "minlon": -79.032897949219,
      "maxlat": 43.842315673828,
      "maxlon": -79.031524658203,
      "medlat": 43.84,
      "medlon": -79.03
    }
  }],
  "zoom": "10"
};
```

```css
#homeMap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.21/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="homeMap"></div>
```

Comment: cheers that was the jist of it I just had to change how I closed any open infowindows