# Can MarkerClusterer have a long click or double click?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, markerclusterer

[Googlemap API v3 - Can I get Content from Marker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289634/googlemap-api-v3-can-i-get-content-from-marker)
This is my last Question.

There is another problem,when markers become MarkerClusterer i set a click event to show all marker avg and show on infowindow.

And,my Question is Can **MarkerClusterer have a long click or double click**?

I mean double click and zoom in like MarkerClusterer click or long click then show infowindow,Because I need to zoom in,and After zoom in how to hide infowindow?

My code in the link.

By the way I try to give markerclusterer "dblclick",like this

```
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers_Select, mcOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'dblclick', function(cluster) {
        var info = new google.maps.MVCObject; 
        info.set('position', cluster.center_); 
        var allmarke = cluster.getMarkers(); 
        var titles = "";
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < allmarke.length; i++) {
            total += parseFloat(allmarke[i]._myValue); 
        }
        titles = "avg：" + (total / (allmarke.length)).toFixed(2);
        g_infoWindow.setContent(titles);
        g_infoWindow.open(map, info);
        });
```

but not work....

Comment: [There is no 'double' click event on a markerCluster](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)

Comment: I see there have a "mouseover" so can i mouseover and show infowindow when "mouseout" infowindows hide? I trying now.